# How to copy casper-rw persistent USB install to a new HDD?

Tags: linux-mint, usb-drive, persistence

I'm somewhat of a beginner with Linux, sorry for the dumb question.

I installed a persistent Linux Mint install to a USB drive. It has been working well, but now I want to install it directly to a new SSD drive I bought.

I thought that using the "Install" option would already copy all my apps and user files to the drive, but as far as I can see it only installed a fresh Linux Mint install, with no apps and my /home folder only has a new user I created with the install.

**Question:** How do I make the exact install I have on the USB drive be copied to the SSD drive?

**Question 2:** Is it possible and advisable to use Timeshift, Clonezilla or another app to make an image of the old Linux install and then recover that image when booting with the new Linux install?

Comment: Is it possible to use a Cloning app and make an image of the old drive and use the new Linux Mint install in the new drive to restore that image? Or would there be issues because of casper-rw? I thought of trying [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/741727) and copying all files of the old install to the new install (except for `/boot` and `/etc/fstab`, also not copying `/tmp`, `/dev`, `/run`, `/mnt`, `/media`). Would this make the system unstable, if it works at all, due to the differences between a casper-rw USB install and a HDD install?

Answer (score 1):

BTW am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Was your personal data `/home/user/` saved on your USB ?

If you rebooted your USB may not have loaded automatically.

Try this command:

```
df -h
```

Look at the left column for `/dev/sda`

If your USB loaded it may shows as  `/dev/sdb`  or similar .

If your USB is plugged in but NOT loaded try this command:

```
fdisk -l
```

You may need use root password, try `sudo fdisk -l`

If `fdisk` command shows your USB is loaded then you may be able to copy your USB `home/user/Documents` across to your SSD drive folder `/home/user/Documents`

If `fdisk` command does not show your USB then read:

```
man mount
man umount
```

Perhaps, also how to `man cp` your USB data across.

Linux is different to MS-Windows, it took myself a while to understand things better.

Apps are programs which process data, store data, or produce results.

Individual users may find their apps settings in the folder `/etc/`

In your terminal try command:  `ls -l /etc/`

If results not clear, try `sudo ls -l /etc/`

Comment: Thanks! I was able to copy my home folder and get the files there, but it didn't copy the apps nor the apps settings. I tried something else, I'll make it an answer

Answer (score 1):

This "worked", but I probably wouldn't recommend it to anyone, except as a last resort.

I installed Linux Mint to my new SSD using the option from my casper-rw USB persistent install. (to my chagrin, it installed a completely new installation, disregarding everything I had in my USB installation)

I backed up the `/etc/fstab` file from the *new* installation.

Booting from the USB drive again, I mounted the new install ( `sudo mount /dev/find-your-own-install-partition /mnt/newinstall` ) then ran this command (taking a cue from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/741727)):

> sudo rsync -a / /mnt/newinstall/ --exclude sys --exclude proc --exclude dev --exclude tmp --exclude media --exclude mnt --exclude run --exclude boot

This will copy everything from the old install to the new install, except for `/sys`, `/proc`, `/dev/`, `/boot` and all the other ones, overwriting duplicate files (that is, new files not present in the old install won't be deleted! Which is possibly a bad idea).

Then I pasted back to the new install its `/etc/fstab` file I backed up. I think this is necessary for booting properly, though you should probably reinstall grub or something.

When I booted the new install, most things were there, but Firefox, for example, started afresh (I need to change default profiles). But it seemed to work.

It did, however, break `apt` and some packages. Fortunately, Linux is so awesome that it fixed everything for me. I just had to go to Software Resources, restore everything to default and remove from Additional Resources the //cdrom repositories. After that, `apt update` worked again and using Update Manager it downloaded and reinstalled whatever it thought was broken.

So far so good, but this doesn't look like the cleanest option possible...

Comment: There is a way via [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb), that is described for Ubuntu and Ubuntu family flavours, that I *think* works also for Linux Mint. See the details about [backup and restore at this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent#Backup_and_restore_of_persistent_overlay_data).